# JRuby database.yml file configuration to use IBM DB2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jdbc, db2, jruby

I have installed:

1. JRuby (1.7.0.preview2)
2. Rails (3.2.8)
3. IBM DB2 Express C (1.01)
4. active-record-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2)

How should I change the database.yml file in order to my rails application to connect to DB2 database?

I have followed this article:

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter

but there is no example with DB2 database. Also, why it is said that I should change Jruby to use always JDBC adapter.

> If you’re using Rails 3, you’ll need to modify your Gemfile to use the
>   activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem under JRuby. Change your Gemfile to look
>   like the following (using sqlite3 as an example):

```
if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
  gem 'jdbc-sqlite3'
else
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

and where should I put the statement above?

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @Wasi, I have a clue, but at all the answer is "No". Could you help me?

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing as you. no luck so far

Comment: gotqn gave a good answer below. For the non-JDBC half of the if-else, you'll want to require ibm_db (http://rubygems.org/gems/ibm_db), not sqlite3-ruby.

Comment: @Leons, as I have read the IBM driver is only compatible with Ruby on Rails, not JRuby.

Comment: @gotqn: If you only care about JRuby for this project, you don't need the if-else statement. The if-else statement is checking for whether it's running under JRuby. If it's not running under JRuby, the if-else loads the sqlite3-ruby gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple working format:

```
development:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
  url: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/devp
  host: localhost
  port: 50000
  database: devp
  username: db2inst1
  password: mypass
```

Note, that you have to:

> Copy db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar to jruby/lib
>   (~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-*/lib) directory.

or in case you are using torquebox:

> Copy db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar to application lib folder.